# An error When I want to validate null fileds and save them in laravel : "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST."

Tags: php, laravel

I wrote a simple code to validate input data and save them. But when I leave some fields null I get this error :

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Despite using the post method.

Laravel Framework **5.8.22** - mysql

`Route::post('/contactus','contactus_controller@store' );`

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  //dd($request->all());

  $this->validate($request ,
    [
      'fullname'  => 'required',
      'email' => 'required',
      'message' => 'required'
    ]
  );

  $usermessage = new Usermessage;
  $usermessage->fullname = $request->get('fullname');
  $usermessage->email = $request->get('email');
  $usermessage->message = $request->get('message');
  $usermessage->username = $request->session()->get('username_session');
  $usermessage->save();

  return 123;
}
```

Comment: can  we see the view?

Comment: if i get you clear, when you leave some input fields blank you get an error.

Comment: When `$this->validate()` fails, it redirects back to the `GET` version of `/contactus`; generally, you have a `GET` route that displays the form for the `POST` request. How are you performing this `POST`? Is it an `ajax` request? Is the `GET` route to display the form something different than `/contactus`?

Comment: In your html, on the form, add `method="post"`.

Comment: Yes I can see the contactus form and until the submit every things is ok. and Even I fill all fileds again is ok and save my data to table. But when I leave one field empty this error raise. 
I didnot use ajax and I  use the get route to display the contactus form : 
Route::get( '/contactus','contactus_controller@create');
And I used the post  method in my form method  : 
<form action="contactus" method="post">

Comment: This is my contactus view : 
<form action="contactus" method="post">
     {{ csrf_field() }}

     <div class="form-group">
      <label> Full name : </label>
      <input type="text" name="fullname" class="form-control">
     </div>
     ... 
     </div>

     <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>

Answer (score 0):

add method="post" in your html form. `<form method = 'POST' action = '{{url("contactus/store")}}' enctype="multipart/form-data">`